# How to make BroadcastReceiver work even if the app is closed or not running...?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

**When my app is running or is minimized, it is working fine.
but when app is closed it doesn't work.**

I want it to work even when it is closed.....please suggest help for this.

**SmsReceiver.java**

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    String str = "hello";
    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            sendToMain(context,intent);
    }

    public void sendToMain(Context context,Intent intent){

        Toast.makeText(context,"from receiver : "+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            

        Intent i = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("msg",str);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
         Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
         sms = extras.getString("msg");

         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "from main activity :"+sms, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 }
```

**Permissions ->**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

**Receiver -->**

```
    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: Actually no one has answered that post yet...so i thought i should post a new one